# SVG Inkscape generated file does not show flowRoot objects on browser

Tags: javascript, html, svg, internet-explorer-9

I´m dealing with SVG file in order to make some realtime animations on browser using AJAX.

Everything is fine except to make the browser (Chrome or IE9) to show the SVG image. The following HTML file does not show the flowRoot Text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="744.09448"
   height="600"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="lcl22.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="175.99454"
     inkscape:cy="282.7269"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="706"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-452.36215)">
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:#008000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#495677;stroke-width:23.16900063;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="circle1"
       sodipodi:cx="227.14285"
       sodipodi:cy="156.6479"
       sodipodi:rx="47.142857"
       sodipodi:ry="44.285713"
       d="m 274.28571,156.6479 c 0,24.45833 -21.10658,44.28572 -47.14286,44.28572 C 201.10657,200.93362 180,181.10623 180,156.6479 c 0,-24.45832 21.10657,-44.28571 47.14285,-44.28571 26.03628,0 47.14286,19.82739 47.14286,44.28571 z"
       inkscape:label="#path2985"
       transform="translate(12.857143,635.71428)" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#00ff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#495677;stroke-width:4.86899996;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="box1"
       width="284.28571"
       height="110"
       x="312.85715"
       y="738.07648"
       inkscape:label="#box1" />
    <flowRoot
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="flowRoot3058"
       style="font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Sans;text-anchor:middle;text-align:center"
       transform="translate(0,452.36215)"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion3060"><rect
           id="rect3062"
           width="365.71429"
           height="100"
           x="221.42857"
           y="145.71428"
           style="text-anchor:middle;text-align:center" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara3064"
         style="font-weight:bold;-inkscape-font-specification:Sans Bold">LCL22 TEST</flowPara></flowRoot>  </g>
</svg>
```

I´ve tried to change the code to version 1.2 by changing the following line, but did not solve the problem...

```
   version="1.2"
```

I need a easy way to edit and bring custom vector graphics to browser. I thought SVG would be a piece of cake, but I´m running aroud these kind of problems...

Any help appreciated.

Rds

Comment: relevant: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/167335

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The SVG 1.2 Full specification was never completed](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG12/) (as you can see from the link it's still in draft from 2005) and only Inkscape ever supported flowRoot I think. I don't think it's intended that flowRoot will be part of SVG 2 either as that is likely to implement flowing text with a different and more CSS compatible mechanism so flowRoot is best avoided.

Use the Convert to text" command in the Text menu to convert it to SVG 1.1 compliant text.

Comment: Opera (Presto) never supported `flowRoot` (which is only in the SVG 1.2 Full draft). It did support `textArea` from SVG 1.2 Tiny (which is a w3c recommendation).

Comment: So, should I change the editor or change the tag. What shall be put instead of flowRoot and derivates ? What editor is better suited ?

Comment: Is there an option to set this as default? I mean, why I have to convert each created text, is there a way to create it already 1.1-compatible?

Comment: If you don't want to edit the text, you can also convert it to path.

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, you can use **convert to text** or **unflow** to remove the flowRoot.

Keep in mind however that the text will no longer stay within the boundary you specified.

To avoid flowRoot going forward, just click with the text tool and start typing rather that first dragging to set a bound for it.

To creat text that fits within a bounding box, I'm not sure what the best method is.