# Simple way to display SVG image in a PyQt window

Tags: python, svg, pyqt

I'm looking for a simple and reliable way for inserting an SVG image in a PyQt window. More precisely, I'm wondering if it's possible to have an SVG image applied to a QLabel. This can be done for PNG images (see code bellow).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

label = QtGui.QLabel()
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('my_image.png')
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
label.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit:**

I need to keep the vector aspect of the SVG image for resizing purpose. So converting the image to PNG before displaying it isn't helping.

Comment: I use GTK rather than Qt, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551690/how-to-render-a-scaled-svg-to-a-qimage) looks relevant.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the post you linked shows solution for Qt (not PyQt), it is used to convert an SVG to a PNG. I may have been not clear enough but it's not what I need. i'd like to keep the vector format so that I can resize the image.

Comment: Sorry. I hoped it would contain enough info for you to adapt it to Python, but I understand doing that's a bit messier than having a totally Python-based solution: I know it's painful looking through C-based stuff when I'm trying to do GTK stuff in Python. But anyway, I _suspect_ that you'll have to display the SVG in a Pixmap, which means that you can't avoid the vector to bitmap conversion. But your code can re-render the SVG in response to scaling commands; that's what I do with SVGs in GTK.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't get it the first time: the code render the SVG to given scale during runtime. This is actually a great solution! I'll try to figure out how to write this for python (PyQt).

Comment: Good luck! If you get stuck, you can add the new code to your question, or just ask a fresh question, possibly linking back to this one. Or if you write a nice solution post it here as an answer: you might pick up a few points, and it may help future readers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`QLabel` only can load a pixmap. If You need a vector-graphic use `QtSvg.QSvgWidget()` and load the svg-file without converting:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtSvg

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget('Zeichen_123.svg')
svgWidget.setGeometry(50,50,759,668)
svgWidget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

or render to any subclass of `QPaintDevice` by `QtSvg.QSvgRenderer` directly, e.g. to `QLabel`:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 

widget = QtGui.QLabel()
widget.setGeometry(50,200,500,500)
renderer =  QtSvg.QSvgRenderer('Zeichen_123.svg')
widget.resize(renderer.defaultSize())
painter = QtGui.QPainter(widget)
painter.restore()
renderer.render(painter)
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[get Zeichen_123.svg here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Zeichen_123.svg)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I'm just having an issue: the SVG image I want to display contains text and it won't show up. Instead of the letters I have black boxes... Any idea?

Comment: I think, this could be a new question. before you ask it with code from your svg-file:
Do other viewers show the svg-file correctly?
are simple <text>-tags in the svg-file or <flowroot>-tags? see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391197/svg-inkscape-generated-file-does-not-show-flowroot-objects-on-browser

Comment: The "black box in place of letters" problem may be due to Qt using the Tiny SVG 1.2 spec. I had this issue as well, see [here](https://www.kdab.com/the-qt-less-traveled/) for more details.