# Custom logo not updating on Thingsboard UI after custom build

Tags: maven, thingsboard

I'm trying to change the logo of the thingsboard UI but for some reason the logo is not updating after the custom build. I have tried rebuilding thingsboard several times and on the following releases:

1.1, 1.2, 1.2.3

The steps I've taken are:

1) Install Java and Maven on Windows 10. - These work as expected.

2) Cloned the source code from https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/

3) Checked out the relevant branch / release. (as per versions listed above)

4) Replaced the the two logos in https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/ui/src/svg with my logos, in same format (svg) and same dimensions. Also replaced the favicon in https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/ui/src .

4a) When building release1.1 I also had to add `SET` to the `NODE_ENV` in package.json. Newer version use a cross platform package which eliminates this requirement.

4b) In another attempt, I built the source without any logos. I.e. the `svg` directory was empty.

4c) I also tried building with and without the mdi.svg file as not sure what it does.

5) The build passes (on each new build attempt) and:

5a) I stop the thingsboard server `net stop thingsboard`

5b) I uninstall thingsboard using uninstall.bat.

5c) I delete the contents of `C:\thingsboard`

5d) I extract the build from `application/target/thingsboard-windows.zip` to `C:\thingsboard`.

5e) I run install.bat

5f) I start the service once more `net start thingsboard`.

- Note that all commands are run in administrator mode using command prompt CLI.

The original thingsboard logo has never changed, even when no logo(s) were present int he source files.

Please note my inexperience with Maven if relevant.

Kindly let me know if I'm missing something or if you have already managed to change the logo(s) / favicon of thingsboard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be 2 issues:

1. Either your SVG is not proper. This happened with me. I created a custom SVG using Inkscape, and it was not backwards compatible with SVG v1.1. You can read more about this issue [on this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391197/svg-inkscape-generated-file-does-not-show-flowroot-objects-on-browser).
2. You're not clearing out the old build files. When building the project afresh with new SVG files, first clear out the old files. This can be done easily using this `git` command:

   ```
   git clean -fdx
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this web: https://www.aconvert.com/image/png-to-svg/ to convert your png to svg. And download svg file, and place it to folder in ui/src/svg of thingsboard.

And then change the top of the file with this, i give attachment of picture to change it. Especially change the svg id.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW0kf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O0AS.png)

Try it, it works for me.